# Terrible performance of Wordpress site on Amazon EC2 + apache2 + ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, wordpress

I'm planning a migration of various wordpress websites (little content), from a shared hosting to a whole new cloud architecture.

I'm using the following:

Amazon EC2 t1.micro
Loaded with:
- Apache2
- Ubuntu Server 12.04

Amazon RDS MySQL micro

I tested it on a small wordpress site, and the performance are really terrible: using Apache AB for benchmark, with -n 1000 -c 10; the requestes are served in more than 2000 ms, so 1-2 seconds for each request (even a very simple request).
I monitored with htop during the bench, and the CPU is always at 100%, and the processes that consumes more are the Apache processes.

How come? It is normal that Wordpress has so high resource needs? Or perhaps it's a problem in my configuration?

I tried to scale to m1.small EC2, but practically nothing changed.

Comment: What are  you using for caching?

Comment: No caching at the moment, I just want to test "pure" apache performance.
In production I'm planning to use Varnish and/or CloudFlare (plus application-side caching in WP).

Comment: I now tested on m1.small EC2 and db.m1.small RDS; but the performance are still really terrible... With ab set a -n 100 and -c 10; the CPU load goes to 100%, and it takes about TEN seconds for each request!

Amazon EC2 "small" machines are crap; or it's due to Wordpress that's extremely high resource needs?

Answer (score 0):

t1.micro instances are useless for everything but the very lowest-load applications, and even then, performance can be very poor.

Your database is on a t1.micro. Upgrade that to an m1.small and see how performance is.

AWS offers some great functionality, automation, as scaling options for large sites, but I'll be honest, the price:performance ratio for smaller sites is not great. You may consider a more "traditional" VPS vendor like Linode or DigitalOcean.

Comment: The strange thing is that even with m1.small the performance are terrible.

Comment: I was thinking of using internal MySQL instead of external RDS. It may be a good solution instead of using a db.t1.micro RDS?

Comment: You tested with your *webserver* on an m1.small. You did not test with your *database* on an m1.small. You should probably do that.

Comment: I now tested on m1.small EC2 and db.m1.small RDS; but the performance are still really terrible...
With ab set a -n 100 and -c 10; the CPU load goes to 100%, and it takes about TEN seconds for each request!